# Why does using arrays instead of string give less memory consumption and time executing?

Tags: java

> Given the string in the form of char array. Modify it the way that all the exclamation point symbols '!' are shifted to the start of the array, and all ohters are in the same order. Please write a method with a single argument of type char[]. Focus on either memory and time consumption of alghoritm.

Feedback that i've received: it was possible to use working with arrays instead of strings. Where can i find info about memory?

```java
public static String formatString(char[] chars) {
    StringBuilder exclamationSymbols = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder otherSymbols = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : chars) {
        if (c == '!') {
            exclamationSymbols.append(c);
        } else {
            otherSymbols.append(c);
        }
    }

    return (exclamationSymbols.toString() + otherSymbols.toString());
}
```

Comment: You're using `StringBuilder`, rather than `String` here (I mean, other than in constructing the result)

Comment: I wonder if you got any _real_ performance tests here

Comment: You would need to benchmark it. I assume the solution being sought is that it is possible to create a char array of the same size as the input and then use only that, or to do the whole thing in place with the input (consider it like a "sort" function).

Comment: You could append otherSymbols to exclamationSymbols. Now you have 2 temporary strings which are immediately discarded. I concur with @Eugene, though. You need a performance test and not rely on a gut feeling.

Comment: Precisely, the assignment explicitly states 'memory [...] consumption of the **algorithm**', so such a difference *should* not be considered for evaluation. It is, nevertheless, a valid thought.

Comment: As an aside, `return exclamationSymbols.append(otherSymbols).toString();` would likely be a more efficient way to form the result, because it avoids creating unnecessary intermediate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this faster using a `char[]` than a `StringBuilder` because:

- a `StringBuilder` is just a wrapper around a `char[]`, so there's no way it can be *faster*. The indirection means it will be slower.
- you know exactly how long the result will be, so you can allocate the minimum-sized `char[]` that you'll need. With a `StringBuilder`, you can pre-size it, but with two `StringBuilder`s you can't exactly, so you either have to over-allocate the length (e.g. make both the same length as `chars`) or rely on `StringBuilder` resizing itself internally (which will be slower than *not*; and it uses moer memory).

My idea would be to use two integer pointers to point to the next position that you'll write a char to in the string: one starts at the start of the array, the other starts at the end; as you work your way through the input, the two pointers will move closer together.

Once you've processed the entire input, the portion of the result array corresponding to the "end pointer" will be backwards, so reverse it.

You can do it like this:

```
char[] newChars = new char[chars.length];
int left = 0;
int right = chars.length;

for (char c : chars) {
  if (c == '!') {
    newChars[left++] = c;
  } else {
    newChars[--right] = c;
  }
}

// Reverse the "otherSymbols".
for (int i = right, j = newChars.length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
  char tmp = newChars[i];
  newChars[i] = newChars[j];
  newChars[j] = tmp;
}

return new String(newChars);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mRlxz3)

Comment: You can save the reversing at the end when you process the input array backwards.

Comment: @Sascha but then you'd have to reverse the head of the array, instead of the tail.

Comment: The head are all exclamation marks. Their order is arbitrary.

Comment: @Sascha hah, true.